# Starting Java 2D Platformer using LWJGL

Tags: opengl, 2d, java, lwjgl, platformer

Getting started on a 2d platforming project in java. I've decided on using LWJGL and OpenGL, but I don't quite know where to start. What is typically the first thing one would work on with a platforming game?

I've never done any game development before, but I'm hoping this will be good practice and hopefully fun to implement and eventually play.

Thanks

Comment: The first thing to do is be able to create a window, render a sprite, and move it around with some sort of controls.  Then move on to physics, and finally content for your game.

Comment: Learning how to use Threads correctly will be very helpful too.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but I would start smaller. And by smaller, I mean Pong.

Comment: @Duck Pong is a great game to start off with, it's like the "Hello World" of game development :)

Comment: Well I guess I have done "some" game dev before, so I'm a bit beyond pong. I did a breakout game and a falling blocks game, so I think it's time to move on. And thanks for the tips guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java + 2D + LWJGL = Use [Slick](http://www.slick2d.org/) library. It's based on LWJGL library and makes it much easier to use for 2D :)
In Slick website, they've very easy and quick tutorials, try it out! I'm sure you will LOVE it! ;)

Since your main question is "Where to start", start from [Slick Wiki page](http://www.slick2d.org/wiki/)!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the platform game specific part of your question:

Platform games are traditionally tile based. Tiles are fixed size rectangles which comprise the building blocks of each level; they can have the appearance of stone, or grass or any surface you can imagine within reason. The best way to design them is to ensure that when two identical tiles are placed next to each other, the texture seamless repeats.

A good example of how to design repeating tile sets is here:

http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2012/03/01/designing-a-retro-pixel-art-tile-set

Tiles are laid out in memory in what is called a 'map'. Each tile is given an identifying number; maps are rectangular arrays containing numerical tile references. An example map might look like this:

```
byte[] map = 
{
   01,01,01,01,01,01,01
   01,00,00,00,00,00,01
   01,00,02,02,02,00,01
   01,00,00,00,00,00,01
   01,01,01,01,01,01,01
};
```

Most platform games have multiple layers of these maps; background tiles generally have no collision information associated with them and are purely decorative, mid-ground tiles can be used to mark locations associated with game-logic, like entrances and exits, or for placing AI characters. Foreground tiles are used for collision information and the main body of the actual platforms.

Maps can be connected together using special tiles which indicate an entrance or exit, when collided with the system can unload the current map and load in the new one.

You can read more about platform games in general here:

http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/12/11/how-to-make-a-2d-platform-game-part-1/

Hope that helps!

Cheers, Paul.